# Using media queries to control image downloads

Tags: image, css, responsive-design, media-queries

If I create a container and want to set a background image based on media queries, why does the browser (Firefox, Chrome) download the medium sized image, if the large one has already been downloaded? That seems totally against the point (i.e. saving bandwidth).

HTML

```
<div id="background"></div>
```

CSS

```
#background {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    background-image: url(/content/images/2016/04/airport-small.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}

@media (min-width: 500px) {
  #background {
    background: url(/content/images/2016/04/airport-medium.jpg);
  }
}
@media (min-width: 800px) {
  #background {
    background: url(/content/images/2016/04/airport-large.jpg);
  }
}
```

If I load a page the browser downloads the `-large.jpg`, in this setup. If I resize the screen (below 800px), the browser downloads and renders the `-medium.jpg`, and so on.

How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the main cause of the conflict here is your assumption that media queries were implemented to save bandwidth. They were implemented to display different things at different sizes, that's all. The fact you've chosen to display the same image at a different size was simply how you decided to utilize them, and media queries are just faithfully doing what they promised to do all along: Show the user what you told it to show the user.

I'd recommend evaluating whether this is really a worthy investment in time and code (keeping in mind that most users won't resize a window or rotate a mobile device, and those who do probably wouldn't be put off by a flash-and-reload). If you decide to do it, it won't be through only CSS. Your best bet will to research JavaScript methods to do this, such as adding a class `loaded-large` to the body tag onload, and then writing a CSS rule for smaller images only to load when the body tag does not have `class='loaded-large'`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

You're re-sizing the window, which is causing multiple media queries to execute, which results in multiple images being downloaded.

But you're a web developer re-sizing your browser for testing purposes. An actual user doesn't normally do this. A user simply lands on your site to do their business – *on one screen size*.

In your case, if this user is on a device with a browser width of 500px - 799px, he/she would get the medium jpg and/or small jpg, depending on the browser (see below).

Note that a user on a screen width greater than 800px may get all three images. (A window that matches `min-width: 800px` also matches `min-width: 500px`.)

Based on a review of [Media Query & Asset Downloading Results](https://timkadlec.com/2012/04/media-query-asset-downloading-results/), browser behavior varies in terms of image download. In particular, see test #4.

---

Also, consider the ***`picture`*** element, which tells the browser which image is most suitable for a particular screen size.

> [**4.8.2 The `picture`
>   element**](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#the-picture-element)
>
> The `picture` element is a container which provides multiple sources
>   to its contained `img` element to allow authors to declaratively
>   control or give hints to the user agent about which image resource to
>   use, based on the screen pixel density, viewport size, image format,
>   and other factors.

```
<picture>
   <source srcset="airport-small.jpg"  media="(max-width: 499px)">
   <source srcset="airport-medium.jpg" media="(min-width: 500px) and (max-width: 799px)">
   <source srcset="airport-large.jpg"  media="(min-width: 800px)">
   <img src="airport-small.jpg" alt="">
</picture>
```

If all `source` elements evaluate to false, the `img` element is applied. This is a useful fallback as `picture` is not supported by  Internet Explorer.

---

References:

- [Media Queries Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) ~ W3C
- [Media Query & Asset Downloading Results](https://timkadlec.com/2012/04/media-query-asset-downloading-results/) ~ Tim Kadlec
- [4.8.2 The `picture` element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#the-picture-element) ~ W3C
- [`picture` definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture) ~ MDN
- [`picture` browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=picture) ~ caniuse.com
- [Polyfill for the `picture` element](https://scottjehl.github.io/picturefill/) ~ Picturefill